# Docker compose linking appears to not work

Tags: postgresql, docker, elixir, docker-compose, phoenix-framework

I'm using Docker Compose to run an Elixir/Phoenix app in development.  The setup is pretty standard, with a postgres container and a web container.

However, I'm having a hard time getting the web container to talk to the database container.

Here is my web container `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
MAINTAINER me@example.com

RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8  
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8  
ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en  
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8 

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y wget
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN apt-get install -y inotify-tools
RUN apt-get install -y postgresql-client
RUN wget https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang-solutions_1.0_all.deb \
    && dpkg -i erlang-solutions_1.0_all.deb
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_5.x | sudo -E bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y esl-erlang 
RUN apt-get install -y elixir
RUN mix local.rebar
RUN mix local.hex --force

ADD . src/blog/
WORKDIR src/blog/

RUN mix deps.get
RUN mix deps.compile
```

Here's my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
db:
  image: postgres
web:
  build: .
  command: mix phoenix.server
  volumes:
    - .:/src/blog
  ports:
    - "4000:4000"
  links:
    - db
```

When I run `docker-compose up`, things appear to work okay.  However, when I try to run (to create the database):

```
$ docker run blogphoenix_web mix ecto.create
```

I get the following error:

> ** (Mix) The database for Blog.Repo couldn't be created, reason given: psql: could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known

Then, if I inspect the hosts file of the web container with:

```
$ docker run blogphoenix_web cat /etc/hosts
```

... I get this output:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.4      a86e4f02ea56
```

Isn't Docker Compose supposed to create a hostname entry for the `db` container?

Here are some relevant version numbers for my Docker tooling:

```
$ docker-machine --version
#=> docker-machine version 0.6.0, build e27fb87
$ docker-compose --version
#=> docker-compose version 1.6.0, build unknown
$ docker --version
#=> Docker version 1.10.0, build 590d510
```

### EDIT

Okay, I just noticed something that may help someone else reading this. This command, `docker run blogphoenix_web cat /etc/hosts` enters a new container, whereas this command `docker exec 845f9d69cb1e cat /etc/hosts` enters a running container.  `845f9d69cb1e` is the container ID for the running version of the `blogphoenix_web` image.

```
$ docker ps

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
845f9d69cb1e        blogphoenix_web     "mix phoenix.server"     About an hour ago   Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:4000->4000/tcp   blogphoenix_web_1
21a6f48dfc3b        postgres            "/docker-entrypoint.s"   About an hour ago   Up 2 minutes        5432/tcp                 blogphoenix_db_1
```

Running the `exec` command I get the expected output from the hosts file, showing the appropriate hostname linkage for the `db` container:

```
$ docker exec 845f9d69cb1e cat /etc/hosts

127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.2      db_1 21a6f48dfc3b blogphoenix_db_1
172.17.0.2      blogphoenix_db_1 21a6f48dfc3b
172.17.0.2      db 21a6f48dfc3b blogphoenix_db_1
172.17.0.3      845f9d69cb1e
```

In other words, when I ran the `docker run blogphoenix_web mix ecto.create` command, I was executing `mix ecto.create` in a new container based on the `blogphoenix_web` image.  This new container wasn't started with `docker-compose` and thus did not have the appropriate host file linkage to the `db` container setup.

Comment: Try running "docker-compose run web mix ecto.create", and you should have linked containers working

Comment: Wow, okay, that worked.  Thank you.  But, I thought that Docker Compose created a hosts entry for the various containers so they could talk to each other.  If not, then where does this linkage exist?

Comment: The linkage exists between containers, not between images. I explained it by example in the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to run it using docker-compose:

```
docker-compose run web mix ecto.create
```

Docker compose creates linked containers, but the images themselves are not linked. This means that blogphoenix_web is not linked to blogphoenix_db, but when you will run

```
docker-compose up
```

the newly created containers "blogphoenix_web_1" and "blogphoenix_db_1" will be linked together.